# Gem::InstallError: The 'http_parser.rb' native gem requires installed build tools. Jekyll website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, jekyll, jekyll-theme

I am trying to build a new website using this jekyll template (https://themeforest.net/item/toile-responsive-jekyll-theme-for-bloggers-and-writers/23079570).

But, when I run the command "bundle install, I got this code error:

```
Installing http_parser.rb 0.6.0 with native extensions
Gem::InstallError: The 'http_parser.rb' native gem requires installed 
build
tools.

Please update your PATH to include build tools or download the DevKit
from 'http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads' and follow the instructions
at 'http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit'
An error occurred while installing http_parser.rb (0.6.0), and Bundler 
cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install http_parser.rb -v '0.6.0' --source
'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Could you please help ? :)

Thanks in advance to the community !

Ps: I'm not a developer, just a curious and motivated guy trying to make this template works.

I carefully followed the "proper" installation reported here: http://jekyll-windows.juthilo.com/1-ruby-and-devkit/

Moreover, I can see the config file of the DevKit in my C: and the path seems OK so I don't understand.

```
PS C:\Users\Matthis\Desktop\EtoileOK\etoile> bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies...
Using public_suffix 3.0.3
Using addressable 2.5.2
Using bundler 2.0.1
Using colorator 1.1.0
Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.4
Using eventmachine 1.2.7 (x64-mingw32)
Fetching http_parser.rb 0.6.0
Installing http_parser.rb 0.6.0 with native extensions
Gem::InstallError: The 'http_parser.rb' native gem requires installed 
build
tools.

Please update your PATH to include build tools or download the DevKit
from 'http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads' and follow the instructions
at 'http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit'

An error occurred while installing http_parser.rb (0.6.0), and Bundler 
cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install http_parser.rb -v '0.6.0' --source
'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
 jekyll-livereload was resolved to 0.2.2, which depends on
em-websocket was resolved to 0.5.1, which depends on
  http_parser.rb
PS C:\Users\Matthis\Desktop\EtoileOK\etoile>
```

I just would like to understand how to solve this issue so I could start working on my personal website :)

Thanks in advance to the community ! ;)

Matt

Comment: I had a similar problem because of this bug: https://github.com/tmm1/http_parser.rb/issues/47 

The easiest (but awkward) solution was making sure there were no spaces in the project's parent directories.